# What options are there for Embedded Scripting in Windows 8 store / Metro Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm currently building a C#/XAML app and I've looked around on google for a solution but I mostly find scripting engine that are not compatible with WinRT/Metro/Windows App Store applications

I would like to be able to pass in an object into the script for processing and provide an API that can be invoked to fetch additional basic information from the Script.

The main reason I am looking into Scripting Engines is we would like to be able to modify a small amount of the application's behaviour without having to redeploy or update.

Similar scripting engines include nashorn and JavaScript Core, the scripting language itself is a secondary concern.